# Return JSON data from with "data"

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I need to populate a jQuery datatable with my database data, but was very difficult to do so. Searching in the web, I believe I have found the cause, which would be the json format returned by my controller. The format should be as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "CODIGO": "CC0050",
      "TEXTO": "USINAGEM"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "CODIGO": "CC0100",
      "TEXTO": "MONTAGEM"
    }]
}
```

but are returning in this format:

```
[
 {
  "ID":24,
  "CODIGO":"CC0050",
  "TEXTO":"USINAGEM"
 },
 {
  "ID":25,
  "CODIGO":"CC0100",
  "TEXTO":"MONTAGEM"
 }
]
```

this is the controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllCECOS()
    {
        using (RPIEntities contextObj = new RPIEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var listaCECOS = contextObj.T0CECOS.ToList();
                return Json(listaCECOS, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return Json( new { data = listaCECOS }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: The only difference is with the first example you'd use `result.data` to be the source of data for your datatable and the latter would simply be `result`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke great, I changed the code indicated and it worked! Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that you are returning the list of objects, and it's the list that  is actually parsed in JSON.

In that case, you want to return an object with the "data" property. It could be a named class as such:

```
public class MyReturningObject
{
    public IEnumerable<T0CECOS> data { get; set; }
}
```

or an anonymous object :

```
return new { data = listaCECOS, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Add the list in this object and parse it in JSON for the actual awaited JSON!

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "CODIGO": "CC0050",
      "TEXTO": "USINAGEM"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "CODIGO": "CC0100",
      "TEXTO": "MONTAGEM"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all,

I changed the return of my JsonResult mothod:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllCECOS()
{
    using (RPIEntities contextObj = new RPIEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var listaCECOS = contextObj.T0CECOS.ToList();
            **return Json(listaCECOS, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);**
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
return Json(new { data = listaCECOS }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This should not be put as an answer. It should either be an edit or comment at best since you've already accepted an answer.